# Run Flutter Android Built App on IOS Device

Tags: ios, flutter, cross-platform

I am very new to flutter and require your help.
I have built my complete flutter app for android, and now I want to test the same on Iphone, how is it possible?
I tried few tutorials starting with "flutter build ios --release" , but nothing is working for me

Comment: Which OS you used for developing flutter application?

Comment: OS is windows 10

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a mac, or use codemagic or get macOS on the VirtualBox on your windows system!

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is required to build and release iOS app. You must use a device running on macOS.

Please refer official doc : https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios

After successfully configuration, use **`flutter build ios`** command to build iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a Mac and Xcode to build and release iOS app.

However, you can use simple external tools to do so.

For example, Odevio (https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI), it is tool that lets you access remote MacOS build machines.

You can install it from the website: https://www.odevio.com